# to Initiatize the child class construtor : Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am not able to assign the value to the child class constructor , using base class constructor. can you help me understand this.

Code:

```
class Polygon
{
    public  int NumSides;

    public Polygon (int numsides)
    {
        this.NumSides = 4;
    }
}

class Square : Polygon
{
    public readonly int SideLength;
    public Square( int SideLength) : base(SideLength)
    {
        this.SideLength = NumSides;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Polygon p = new Polygon(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Polygon Class {0}", p.NumSides);
        Square s = new Square(1);
        Console.WriteLine("SquareClass {0}", s.SideLength);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> Result: Polygon Class: 4, SquareClass: 0

If I modify to :

```
class Square : Polygon
{
    public readonly int SideLength;
    public Square( int SideLength) : base(SideLength)
    {
        this.SideLength = NumSides;
    }
}
```

It works.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting this result with this code ?

Comment: Isn't your modified code the same as the original code?

Comment: Output is in fact: Polygon Class 4, SquareClass 4

Comment: Why aren't you using the value passed to the Polygon constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up NumSides (part of the Polygon base class) and SideLength (only in Square).

I'm guessing you wanted those classes to be :

```
class Polygon
{
    public int NumSides;

    public Polygon(int numsides)
    {
        this.NumSides = numsides;
    }
}

class Square : Polygon
{
    public readonly int SideLength;
    public Square(int SideLength) : base(4)
    {
        this.SideLength = SideLength;
    }
}
```

ie assign NumSides in the Polygon constructor and SideLength in the Square constructor - but pass 4 for NumSides  to the base constructor in Square.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes , u are right I made it to work finally, you are spot on:    public readonly int sideLength;
    public Square(int sideLength) : base(4)
    {
        this.SideLength = sideLength;
    }
}